# How Can I Detect 1500 Random Lines From a big Text File in Java?

Tags: java, random

I'm new in Java. I have a school project. I should detect 1500 random lines of a big text file? Actually, the text file includes 5 million lines. I want to read line by line a .txt file, then detect 1500 lines randomly, and write the random lines into the new .txt file
Would you please help me in this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "choose" instead of "detect"? Can you choose a line more than once? What have you tried?

Comment: One should try to solve a (trivial) problem before asking for help: therefore, downvote.

Comment: I was correctly reminded of the difference between answers and comments so:

StackOverflow is not really a homework site so we do not answer those sorts of questions. If were to have a good go and show some understanding, and then come to us with small, atomic problems we would be more than happy to help in a way that will expand your learning.

That aside, welcome to SO and I hope you enjoy your time here.

Comment: I am trying with RandomAccessFile, LineIterator and classic BufferedReader approach, but those don't seem to be good solutions.

Comment: Dear Joni, you are right. I mean Choose instead of Detect. I'll so  thankful if you help me .

Answer (score 0):

Just choose 1500 random numbers between 0 and 5 000 000 and get lines by this numbers from file.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a scanner object to parse the file:

```
File file = new File("filename.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Then, use the `.nextLine()` method to read in each line, using a new random int to change which line is being read:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int  randomInt;
String line;

for (int j = 0; j < 1500; j++){
    randomInt =  = rand.nextInt(numberOfLinesInFile + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < randomInt + 1; i++) {
        line = scanner.readLine();
    }
    newString += line;
}
```

`newString` will then contain the new list of 1500 lines

You could also generate 1500 random numbers, creating an array of lines to read, then only add the line that is being read if a counter equals those line numbers. This would reduce the number of loops to achieve the same outcome. The above should be more than enough to get you going...